# Angular bootstrap date-range-picker in a popup?

Tags: angular, popup, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to show a date-range picker in my angular app using ng-bootstrap. My code looks like following:

```
<ngb-datepicker #dp ngModel (ngModelChange)="onDateChange($event)" [displayMonths]="2" [dayTemplate]="t">
            </ngb-datepicker>

            <ng-template #t let-date="date" let-focused="focused">
              <span class="custom-day"
                    [class.focused]="focused"
                    [class.range]="isFrom(date) || isTo(date) || isInside(date) || isHovered(date)"
                    [class.faded]="isHovered(date) || isInside(date)"
                    (mouseenter)="hoveredDate = date"
                    (mouseleave)="hoveredDate = null">
                {{ date.day }}
              </span>
            </ng-template>
```

How should I show the above range picker in a pop-up?

As per an answer, I tried the following but the popup is not visible on click:

```
 <!-- Button trigger modal -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
            Pick Date Range
           </button>

    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Optional title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

            <ngb-datepicker #dp ngModel (ngModelChange)="onDateChange($event)" [displayMonths]="2" [dayTemplate]="t">
            </ngb-datepicker>

            <ng-template #t let-date="date" let-focused="focused">
              <span class="custom-day"
                    [class.focused]="focused"
                    [class.range]="isFrom(date) || isTo(date) || isInside(date) || isHovered(date)"
                    [class.faded]="isHovered(date) || isInside(date)"
                    (mouseenter)="hoveredDate = date"
                    (mouseleave)="hoveredDate = null">
                {{ date.day }}
              </span>
            </ng-template>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display your date-range-picker in a **Bootstrap 4** popup/modal, you can use the following HTML as a template (click the "run code snippet" button below for a live test).

### Important for `ng-bootstrap` users:

The `popper.js` is required in Bootstrap 4 for all things that pop up or drop down. So, make sure you load that in your application.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Click this button!
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Optional title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Your date-range-picker code goes here...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Reference:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried putting the date picker in the modal-body div like you had in your example but on clicking I dont see the div.

Comment: *popper.js* is your friend for all things that pop up or drop down in Bootstrap 4. Make sure you load it. See my code snippet.

Comment: That explains it. I will try putting it. Thanks for your guidance on this.

Comment: Alternatively, you can load *bootstrap.bundle.min.js* because that includes popper.js

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to use a full-fledged popup, but rather show the date range picker in a flyout, I made a simple demo using [ng-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/ng-bootstrap) and [moment.js](/questions/tagged/moment.js): https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-bootstrap-date-range

It heavily borrows from the official [range selection demo](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples#range) provided by ng-bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks for the only working sample of this feature on angular 2+ out there

Comment: perfect use of ngb-datepicker, great work. and the best example here, this should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for explained reply and solution, yes while we are using only bootstrap 4 then we might need the dependencies stated over. But these are not needed while we are working with ng-bootstrap, I got it from the official documentation of  [Ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) .

Please add your valued comments to it, I am new to learning Angular and its extensions, please clear my doubt too.