# How to create ng-bootstrap date range picker popup from button element

Tags: angular5, twitter-bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to add functionality for the daterangepicker to allow for filtering of a list of items based on the date range selected.

I am looking to incorporate the following functionlity:

1. Have a button that says "Filter". No input.
2. User can click on that button which then opens the calendar showing 2 months - the current and next.
3. User can then select a date range.
4. The selected date range then becomes the label of the button showing the user what he or she selected.

Is this functionality possible? It breaks completely when I try to add the calendar on the button. And when I use the input to popup the calendar it only allows me to select a start date, then closes.

Here is what I am going for:

```
<button #dp ngModel (click)="d.toggle()" (ngModelChange)="onDateChange($event)" [displayMonths]="2" [dayTemplate]="t" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
         Click Me
</button>


<ng-template #t let-date="date" let-focused="focused">
    <span class="custom-day"
    [class.focused]="focused"
    [class.range]="isFrom(date) || isTo(date) || isInside(date) || isHovered(date)"
    [class.faded]="isHovered(date) || isInside(date)"
    (mouseenter)="hoveredDate = date"
    (mouseleave)="hoveredDate = null">
    {{ date.day }}
</ng-template>
```

Thanks

Comment: Auto close has been added.  That allows you to pick a range.  I have not been able to change ngModel, but in looking at the api I would imagine you would have to take advantage of "useClass" and override one of the datepicker services.  Wondering if you have been able to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular bootstrap date-range-picker in a popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48752489/angular-bootstrap-date-range-picker-in-a-popup)